# Why pgrep hangs when clang AddressSanitizer library is preloaded using LD_PRELOAD?

Tags: gcc, freeze, ld, clang, pgrep

I noticed that when I set LD_PRELOAD env. variable to libclang_rt.asan-x86_64.so pgrep hangs.

Why is this happening and how to avoid this?

```
senx:/$ time pgrep anything

real    0m0,022s
user    0m0,001s
sys     0m0,020s
senx:/$ export LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libasan.so.4
senx:/$ time pgrep anything

real    0m0,076s
user    0m0,033s
sys     0m0,027s
senx:/$ export LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/llvm-10/lib/clang/10.0.0/lib/linux/libclang_rt.asan-x86_64.so 
senx:/$ time pgrep anything
^C

real    0m33,077s
user    0m0,010s
sys     0m0,010s
```

Comment: Probably because libclang_rt.asan-x86_64.so is replacing a function used by pgrep, and that replaced function is doing something which breaks pgrep.   Weird things happen when using LD_PRELOAD.  That's kind of its purpose.  It's up to the user (you) to only preload libs that are compatible with the programs you want to run with it.